# Multiplication of 2 lists of array with matching indices

Tags: python, numpy

Given 2 lists of arrays (or 2 3D arrays) is there a smarter way in numpy, besides a loop, to get the multiplication of the first array of the first list times the first array of the second list and so on? I have a feeling I am overlooking the obvious. This is my current implementation:

```
import numpy as np

r = []

for i in range(np.shape(rz)[2]):
    r.append(ry[..., i] @ rz[..., i])
r = np.array(r)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the last dimension is the same, [numpy.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) should do the trick:

```py
import numpy as np

np.einsum('ijk,jmk-> imk', ry, rz)
```

Comment: oh that's neat. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[3, 6, 7], [5, -3, 0]])

B = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, -3]])

C = A.dot(B)

print(C)
```

Output:

[[ 36 -12] [ -1   2]]

Comment: Hi Adham, thanks for your answer but the problem was a different one.